# Create own Vue2 component with radio, how to change value

Tags: javascript, binding, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a custom component with radio buttons, but only get a way for work using value of label, instead a value prop.

Example, instead label 1, 2, 3 => Display label "All", "Private", "Professional" and get value 1,2,3

Code snippet not work but [external link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwk7yo5l0n) to codesandbox works.

```js
Vue.component('radio-button', {
  props: ['name', 'label', 'value'],
  template: `
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" :value="label" :name="name" v-model="radioButtonValue">
      <span>{{ label }}</span>
    </label>
  `,
  
  computed: {
      radioButtonValue: {
        get: function() {
          return this.value
        },

        set: function() {
          this.$emit("change", this.label)
        }
      }
});


Vue.component('example-form', {
  template: `
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-centered">
      Test for component with radio buttons
    </div>
    <div>
      <radio-button name="options" label="1" :value="selectedAdvertiser" @change="changeAdvertiser"/>
      <radio-button name="options" label="2" :value="selectedAdvertiser" @change="changeAdvertiser"/>
      <radio-button name="options" label="3" :value="selectedAdvertiser" @change="changeAdvertiser"/>
      <hr>
      <div class="result">
        Radio button selection: {{selectedAdvertiser}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      selectAdvertiser: "1"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeAdvertiser: function(newValue) {
      this.selectedAdvertiser = newValue
    }
  }
});

var App = new Vue({
  el: '#my-app"
  template: `<example-form></example-form>`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<body>
    <div id="my-app"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are using value.

In DropDownComponent.vue:

```
  <radio-button name="options" label="1" :value="selectedAdvertiser" @change="changeAdvertiser"/>
  <radio-button name="options" label="2" :value="selectedAdvertiser" @change="changeAdvertiser"/>
  <radio-button name="options" label="3" :value="selectedAdvertiser" @change="changeAdvertiser"/>
```

The value is identical in all 3 radio buttons but should be the unique value of that radio-button option is selected.

eg:

```
  <radio-button name="options" label="1" value="One" @change="changeAdvertiser"/>
  <radio-button name="options" label="2" value="Two" @change="changeAdvertiser"/>
  <radio-button name="options" label="3" value="Three" @change="changeAdvertiser"/>
```

also, if you emit `input` instead of `change`, your DropDownComponent can access the value as per following:

```
  <radio-button name="options" label="1" value="One" v-model="selectedAdvertiser"/>
  <radio-button name="options" label="2" value="Two" v-model="selectedAdvertiser"/>
  <radio-button name="options" label="3" value="Three" v-model="selectedAdvertiser"/>
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't understan anything. If change DropDownComponent, 1 or 2 example? So, what its radiobuttoncomponent. I try several  options and not get solution. thanks @AlexSamartSky